# ImportError: No module named tktable

Tags: python, tkinter, tktable

I'm trying to import `tktable` to create a simple table, but I'm getting the error below:

> File "prob.py", line 7, in 
>       import tktable ImportError: No module named tktable

```
from tkinter import *
import tktable

root = Tk()
root.title("Probabilidade e estatistica")

table = tktable.Table(root, rows=2, cols=10)
table.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tktable isn't part of the standard library.  you'll need to install it.

Comment: Did You know any tutorial to install tktable library on ubuntu?

Comment: Nope.  I had never actually heard of the library before this question.  (or if I had heard of it, I don't remember it).

Comment: Problem is, TkInter doesn't come with any support for tables *in general*, so there's simply no real other option, except installing it from outside sources.

Comment: Tkinter supports tables via treeview

Answer (score 2):

`tktable` isn't part of the standard `tkinter` package, meaning it's not a built-in feature.

You can [download the `tktable` package from the Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/) website.

Answer (score 0):

`tktable` does not come with the Python standard distributions, unfortuntely. Thus, you need to download and copy it to your working directory or put it under the `site-packages` folder of your Python distribution.

`tktable` is a wrapper library around the homonymous library for the Tcl language and its `Tk` GUI toolkit. It was written by Guilherme Polo (the guy who wrote `ttk`). It supports images, embedded windows, varying colors and fonts, and more.

You can download a version of `tktable` which supports both Python 3 and Python 2 from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/dossan/tktable), where you can find other information on how to use it. A version for Python 2 is also available [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTableWrapper). If you need a complete reference of all supported options, the ActiveState [documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.6/tktable/tkTable.html) on the Tcl/Tk TkTable might be the best way to go for now.

Comment: I've installed it locally, etc. but it seems TkTable (the Tcl/Tk part) is unmaintained, and has been removed from repos. I'm a little wary if I should actually use the old and unmaintained TkTable implementation and wing it from there...

Comment: @polemon I suppose that the ActiveState version of Tcl/Tk's `tktable` is maintained, but you better ask for a precise answer on their forums.

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 3, I get this message:  "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"".

Comment: @LarsEricson What doesn't work? Have you first installed the underlying Tk library called `tktable`?

Comment: There is no underlying tktable for Python 3.4, according to pip.  Also, it was complaining about "table", not "tktable". I used the tktable.py from [here](https://github.com/nbro/tktable), just ran python tktable.py, I didn't run setup because it seems there is only 1 file there.

Comment: @LarsEricson You should describe exactly your directory structure.

Comment: Actually per an answer below there is no standard distribution for tktable except on SourceForge, I will try to find it on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/).....and that's not so good, it gives a C source file I have to unpack twice and then figure out how to build, not so easy.

Comment: @LarsEricson That won't work either. The Python library you can find in the Github repository I am mentioning is exactly the same as the one on the Sourceforge website. I only introduced the possibility to make it work for both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162846/discussion-between-nbro-and-lars-ericson).

Comment: Sorry @nbro I think I will give up.  The file on GitHub requires presence of tktable and I don't have an easy way to install tktable for Python 3.4 for Windows.